# Custom Expandable list with dynamically add child row functionality

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-custom-view

I have screen as i posted here. In this screen there is a expandable listview with child items with add button at 0 position to add new child. When I click child item again view must be visible and I can add child item for it on ADD Field button click. Please give me some idea how can I do this or please post code snippet if you have done ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is multilevel expandable listview , you can do it by adding view at run time and using that do set tag and get tag for getting sub item visible- in visible for example

```
private void generateList(final ArrayList<Beanclass> arrayList)
    {
        View view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        try
        {
            llContainerremoveAllViews();

            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.header_row, null, false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                    viewHolder.rlHeader = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlHeader);
                    viewHolder.imgUser = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
                    viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                    viewHolder.txtAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
                    viewHolder.llContainerChild = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llContainerChild);
                    view.setTag(viewHolder);

                    viewHolder.txtName.setText(arrayList.get(i).name);
                    viewHolder.txtAddress.setText(arrayList.get(i).business_address);

                    String imgUrl = arrayList.get(i).user_img_url;
                    if (imgUrl != null && !imgUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Picasso.with(MainAcitivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(viewHolder.imgUser);
                        viewHolder.imgUser.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    }

                    generateListChild(viewHolder.llContainerChild, arrayList.get(i).arrayListUser, arrayList.get(i).id);

                    ViewHolderChild holderChild = new ViewHolderChild();
                    holderChild.llContainerChildView = viewHolder.llContainerChild;

                    arrayListViewHolderChilds.add(i, holderChild);

                    viewHolder.rlHeaderCurrentBooking.setTag(i);
                    viewHolder.rlHeaderCurrentBooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

                            for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++)
                            {
                                if (j == pos)
                                {
                                    if (arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag == false)
                                    {
                                        arrayListViewHolderChilds.get(j).llContainerChildView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag = true;
                                    }
                                    else if (arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag == true)
                                    {
                                        arrayListViewHolderChilds.get(j).llContainerChildView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag == true)
                                    {
                                        arrayListViewHolderChilds.get(j).llContainerChildView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        arrayList.get(j).expand_Flag = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    llContainerBooked.addView(view);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            Log.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e + "");
        }
    }
```